# Second parameter of a Woocommerce hooked function returns NULL instead of an Object

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, parameters, hook-woocommerce

In the Woocommerce documentation, the `woocommerce_get_price_html` filter hook located in `get_price_html()` method is supposed to take a callback that accepts up to **two parameters**, a price and a product.

But when I try to access the product, I get a `NULL` instead of the WC_Product Object.

Here is my testing code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', function( $price, $item ) {
    echo var_dump ($item); // NULL
    return $price;
});
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: This is just off the top of my head, but doesn't add_filter take a parameter saying how many parameters the callback takes?

Comment: @Chipster why yes it does!  And that parameter defaults to 1, which makes it clear why I was getting NULL for my second parameter.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the 2 parameters that you are using for this hook, in your hooked function, just after the hook priority, this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', function( $price, $product ) {
    echo var_dump ($product); // The WC_Product object instance
    return $price;
}, 10, 2 );
```

And it's better to name your function, like:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'filter_woocommerce_get_price_html', 10, 2 ); 
function filter_woocommerce_get_price_html( $price, $product ) {
    echo var_dump ($product); // The WC_Product object instance
    return $price;
}
```

This time you should be able to get the variable `$product` object…

> See documentation for [add_action()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) and [add_filter()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) WordPress functions.

Comment: thanks!  Why is it better to name your function rather than create an anonymous one?

Comment: @SamRitter Because it allow to set a readable and usable reference for the hooked function that can be used further (later). It's a good habit to take, just like commenting, formatting your code or adding understandable variables names… Also if you need to reuse the hook and you use an anonymous function again you will get an error.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

There are  3 places where this filter is hooked. Three of them have two parameters.

Try this way if though

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'alter_price', 10, 2 );

function alter_price( $price, $item ) {
    echo var_dump ($item); 
    return $price;
}
```